# Is a separate usb signal generator and scope more accurate or flexible than a combination unit?

Tags: tools, test

I have the option of buying an integrated usb function generator/scope, for instance [Velleman PCSGU250](http://www.vellemanusa.com/products/view/?id=524708) or separate oscilliscope (eg [Velleman PCSU1000](http://www.vellemanusa.com/products/view/?id=522377)) and function generator (eg [Velleman PCGU1000](http://www.vellemanusa.com/products/view/?id=523616)). Given that I have a couple ancient laptops lying around, which would enable me to use the separate units on separate systems, would I achieve greater accuracy or flexibility with the separate units than with the combination?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This big advantage of the combined SCope & generator is the BODE PLOT functions.
This is very useful for transfer functions and using the internal FM control to control the X axis of the scope without having to connect it and calibrate it.

Nice choice of stuff. Looks decent,great plots, on the surface.

Comment: Thanks a bunch tony, and your compliments are much appreciated. If I may be so bold, I would commend this to the attention of the fine folks here who keep trying to get me to buy used agilent/hp units

Comment: Well I loved the versatility of a 20MHz 20V Wavetek, AM-FM-Pulse- vbl pulse generator and my TEK digital scope, but many times I need a BODE plot circuit and this is the best I've seen so far. How much was it?  But some Agilent had internal 10MHz reference OCXO which are also worth around $300~$400 alone. 1e-11 stability. So then so does 50/60Hz..... and thats free.

Comment: I was quoted $350

Comment: @TonyStewart, if you like the question upvote! That is not part of an answer. On the question side, there is not decrease in sampling speed or latency by having an all in one?